# Coffeescript iteration over array of objects does not compile as expected

Tags: coffeescript

I would like to perform an iteration over an array of objects. Instead of writing

```
for item in items
  for k, v in item
    # Do Something
```

I would like to do something similar to this

```
for k,v of item in items
  # Do something
```

Which based on the compiled output is not supported:

```
var k, ref, ref1, v, indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { if (i in this && this[i] === item) return i; } return -1; };

ref1 = (ref = indexOf.call(items, item) >= 0) != null ? ref : [];
for (k in ref1) {
  v = ref1[k];
  # Do something
}
```

Is there any other comprehension-like operation through which I can perform this shortcut?

**EDIT:** I can refer to specific keys in the object by doing

```
for { k1, k2 }, i in items
  # Do something
```

For the sake of the question, assume the keys are dynamic

Comment: You have two nested loops for two levels of your data structure, wouldn't it be terribly confusing if you only used one `for`?

Comment: You mean in terms of readability? not particularly. Quite frankly, I think the CoffeeScript Language keywords make it easier to figure out what's going on in terms of a single for loop. If you mean programmatically, I think that this is something that CoffeeScript should be able to do, at least in theory, although I cannot find any documentation supporting that theory.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Following coffeescript's golden rule *“it's just JavaScript”*, consider looking [at the source where a `for` loop gets translated](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/src/nodes.coffee#L2009). You will need two Javascript `for`s and you only can get one from a coffescript `for` (the `for` gets inserted in line 2079).
The javascript result you want to have is something like this:

```
for(_i…;…;…){
  var _x = items[_i];
  for(k in _x){
    var v = _x[k]
    …
}}
```

There are only two ways to get a javascript `for` loop (apart from the prewritten ones, like in class definitions): On [“Range compilation”](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/master/src/nodes.coffee#L885), which always gives a `for(…;…;…)` loop (which contructs an array inside a closure that will be returned) and for the `for` construct.

Your example to access single keys works because you are using some very special case of destructuring assignment. What you would need is a destructuring that extracts key-value pairs and there is none. If you look at the compiled example constructs like this get translated into `a=items[i].a` so such that there is no iteration. You even can omit the `,i`:

```
for {a} in items
  #iterate over the .a values of items
```

If your `#Do something` is just one line, you can put your `for`s on one line, but I personally think it doesn't increase the readability.

```
console.log [k,v] for k,v of i for i in items
```